# Invocation target Exception in Construtor - JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, invocationtargetexception

I am building a javafx project in which I am facing some problems listed below.

First, I was getting a NullPointerException when i was not initializing the 2 classes in constructor `sfc = new ServerFrameController();` & `sf = new ServerFrame();`.Even after searching for hours, I was not able to figure out the cause for the null pointer exception. Then i thought maybe initializing the classes might help. But After adding these two lines I am getting `InvocationTargetException`. Please help!!

## Exception:

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError  
    at com.socket.ServerFrameController.<init>(ServerFrameController.java:35)  
    at com.socket.ServerFrame.<init>(ServerFrame.java:28)
```

Class 1:

```
public class ServerFrame extends Application {

    public ServerFrameController sfc;
    public SocketServer server;
    public Thread serverThread;
    public String filePath = "D:\\Data.xml";
    public JFileChooser fileChooser;
    public JFXPanel fxPanel;

    public ServerFrame() {
        sfc = new ServerFrameController();
        fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        fxPanel.setVisible(true);
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    }
    // Some More Code.....
}
```

Class 2:

```
public class ServerFrameController implements Initializable {

    ServerFrame sf;
    @FXML
    public TextField jTextField3;
    @FXML
    public Button jButton2;
    @FXML
    public Button jButton1;
    @FXML
    public TextArea jTextArea1;

    public ServerFrameController() {
        sf = new ServerFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `ServerFrameController` is calling `ServerFrame` which is calling again `ServerFrameController`. Your `ServerFrameController` should receive your `ServerFrame` as argument.

Comment: I am not very familiar with JavaFX, so I only write a comment instead of an answer. While instantiating a `ServerFrame` this instantiates also a `ServerFrameController` which in turn instantiates a `ServerFrame` which ... You got the point. This leads to a `StackOverflowError`. I assume you want to have a constructor `ServerFramController(ServerFrame sf) { this.sf = sf; ... }` and a call in `ServerFrame`'s constructor: `sfc = new ServerFrameController(this)`.

Comment: Why are you instantiating the controller at all? Typically controller instances are created for you by the `FXMLLoader` when you load an FXML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the issue of `StackOverflowError` by passing a reference to the `ServerFrame` to the controller, but in general it is bad practice to pass a reference of `this` from within the constructor.

```
public class ServerFrameController implements Initializable {

    ServerFrame sf;
    @FXML
    public TextField jTextField3;
    @FXML
    public Button jButton2;
    @FXML
    public Button jButton1;
    @FXML
    public TextArea jTextArea1;

    public ServerFrameController(ServerFrame sf) {
        this.sf = sf;
    }
}
public class ServerFrame extends Application {

    public ServerFrameController sfc;
    public SocketServer server;
    public Thread serverThread;
    public String filePath = "D:\\Data.xml";
    public JFileChooser fileChooser;
    public JFXPanel fxPanel;

    public ServerFrame() {
        sfc = new ServerFrameController(this);
        fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        fxPanel.setVisible(true);
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    }
    // Some More Code.....
}
```

Best would probably be to figure out the NullPointerException and find the proper solution for that. I would guess that is is somehow related to the order everything is initialized.

Comment: "but in general it is bad practice to pass a reference of this from within the constructor" => Why? I ask because this is perfectly valid and it is not a _bad practice_. Note, that only another constructor is called with the `this` reference, not an arbitrary method. Constructors - in general - should not do anything besides storing references and initializing an object. In this scenario, it is safe.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5 share reference from constructor broke final field